# CMDER - Is it possible to send a signal to another (already opened) tab in CMDER / conemu?

Tags: conemu, cmder

So, I have a setup on my CMDER where I can enter a command and 3 new tabs each running a different task (in this case running frontend, backend and worker for one application). I was wondering if it was possible for me to send the ctrl+c signal to each of those from within the first tab (after running the command I'd have 4 tabs running, the one still a prompt, and 3 running commands). Is that something possible?

Comment: You may group input. Look into hotkeys.